# A challenge which improve my skills at programming python?

Tags: python, challenge-response

I have just started programming and I have done quite a few online courses. I know most of the basics like loops,commands,lists ext. I was wanting a challenge where I could use my skills in a python program and extend my knowledge of actually using my skills.

Comment: Did you try Googling "python programming challenges"?

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python  --- Try Here

Answer (score 1):

**There are Many Online Challenges WebSite That Offer You to improve Your Skills and Learn Online., You Can Google it !!**

- https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python
- http://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/
- https://coderbyte.com/course/learn-python-in-one-week